# Calling COM Method From UI Thread Problem

Tags: com, asynchronous, delegates

I wonder if you could help me solve my COM problem.
I have a program that calls a COM method when the button is clicked. The code looks something like this:

```
private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    p.Send(allChanges);
}
```

This code works fine. But I have another program that calls the same COM method. the code looks like this:

```
private void Publish(List<Tuple<string, DataPair>> allChanges)
{
    var d = new SendCallback(Send);
    d.BeginInvoke(allChanges, null, null);
}
```

As you can see here I invoke the COM method using a delegate. If I don't use delegate, the program will crash due to COM exception.

The underlying Send function is the same.

Could anyone please advise? Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you happen to have COM exception details?

Comment: This is the COM exception:Faulting module name: MSVCR80.dll, version: 8.0.50727.6195, time stamp: 0x4dcddbf3
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001500a
Faulting process id: 0x337c

Comment: This is in-process our out-of-process server? More looks like in-process, and if so, does the exception take place in caller thread, or in a background thread?

Comment: In-process. the exception takes place in the caller thread (I use user control). In the Publish function, if I add if(InvokeRequired), it always returns false because it's in UI thread

Comment: What is the exact signature of the COM Send method? (IDL) HRESULT Send([in] LPDISPATCH data): ?